# Using interface for writing save data to a file

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, file-handling

So it's like I have stumbled across a **design related** problem and can't sort it out which is as follows... I have **Two Classes** which use different **structs** for **storing and processing** their data in memory. There is another class for **storing data** basically on a **file** named **File_Data_Handler** which itself **implements an Interface IDController** for reading ,writing ,searching , deletion operation on the file. Now the point where I am facing real **problem is how to establish an elegant channel** for **communication** between the **interface and the classes** for writing data based on **different structs** while keeping the code related to data writing mechanics in **File_Data_Handler** same. Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance. Here is the code **Interface**

```
public interface IDInterface
{

    /*Read data from the source*/
    object ReadData(params object[] _args);

    /*Write data from the source*/
    void WriteData(params object [] _args);

    /*Remove data from the source*/
    bool RemoveData(params object[] _args);

    /*Remove all data from the source*/
    bool RemoveAll(params object[] _args);

}
```

Code for File data writer...

```
public class File_Data_Handler : IDInterface
{

    #region Attribute/Properties

    /*Private Variables*/
    private XmlWriter _writer = null;   //Content writer for class.
    private string _fileLocation="";    //Content storage location.
    private string _fileName = "";  //Content file name.

    #endregion

    #region Compiler Implicit Callbacks

    /*Constructor*/
    public File_Data_Handler(string _fileLocation,string _fileName)
    {

        /*Instance Initialization*/
        this._fileLocation = _fileLocation;
        this._fileName = _fileName;

        /*Make file ready*/
        FileExistanceFlag(_fileName,_fileLocation);

    }

    #endregion

    #region Base overriden Methods

    /*Read data from the source*/
    public object ReadData(params object[] _args)
    {
        return "";
    }

    /*Write data from the source*/
    public void WriteData(params object[] _args)
    {

    }

    /*Remove data from the source*/
    public bool RemoveData(params object[] _args)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /*Remove all data from the source*/
    public bool RemoveAll(params object[] _args)
    {
        return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Processing Methods

    /*Check file existance*/
    private void FileExistanceFlag(string _fileName,string _fileLocation)
    {

        if (!File.Exists(_fileLocation + _fileName))
        {
            File.Create(_fileLocation + _fileName);
        }

    }

    #endregion


}
```

Classes containing structs which need to be written

```
    public classA
{
 public structA
  {
   public int id;
   public string name;
   public string path;
  }
}

public classB
{
 public structB
  {
   public int id;
   public string name;
  }
}
```

Now how can i map these different struct through an interface so that that can be written to a file. Any elegant solution to this design problem will be appreciated.

Comment: You asked me a question, what was the question?  I could potentially help you further, I was incredibly busy when you asked.  Thus, the lack of a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, but I believe the following example will elaborate how to achieve your goal.

```
public interface IDataProcessor<TConfiguration>
{
     IEnumerable<TEntity> Read<TEntity>(TConfiguration configuration);
}
```

Fairly straight forward code, you have two generics one for the object you're hoping to build, another for a configuration to associate or interaction to accomplish your task.

```
public class TextFileProcessor : IDataProcessor<TextFileConfiguration>
{
     private readonly TextFileConfiguration configuration;

     public TextFileProcessor(TextFileConfiguration configuration) => this.configuration = configuration;

     public IEnumerable<TEntity> Read<TEntity>(configuration)
     {
         // Map, based on data from configuration and create object.
         // More...
     }
}
```

The above could simulate a processor for a text file.  While below, will simulate a different type.

```
public class ExcelFileProcessor : IDataProcessor<ExcelFileConfiguration>
{
    private readonly ExcelFileConfiguration configuration;

    public ExcelFileProcessor(ExcelFileConfiguration configuration) => this.configuration = configuration;

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Read<TEntity>(configuration)
    {
         // Map based on data from configuration and create object.
         // More...
    }
}
```

So the two classes inherit the interface, but the implementations are completely separate. By using a configuration object generic, it allows additional flexibility.  I believe this is the conceptual notion you're seeking.